# UITabbar View overlap title on image after present the another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am using the `UITabbarview` with for item. For every tabbar item I am using the image and title.

Its perfect when I come that `TabbarViewcontroller` screen and navigate to another to anther `UIViewcontroller` by push.

But if i navigation to another `UIViewController` by present then come back to same `TabbarviewController` screen then title overlap on image of bar item.

like the images [image]

[image]

Now I am not able to understand, why this happening and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is there any customization for the tabBar being done in viewWillAppear of your TabBarViewController?

Comment: add code for how to present controller ?

Answer (score 1):

use this code in your "viewWillAppear" method.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
      [UITabBarItem appearance].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -3);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Select tab bar icon and choose image inset all = 0